# What does conversion error mean in jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

Anyone has any idea what does this error mean?

```
ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler
```

I recently upgraded the version of jmeter in local windows machine. Version upgrade works well on windows but while trying to run same on linux machine I get above error.

Can anyone suggest how to make it run on linux machine too?  What does this error mean?

Comment: what command are you running to get the error? is it on basic starrtup?

Comment: sh jmeter -n -t ./jmeter/TradingServiceTest.jmx     Trying to run in non gui mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably there is an error in your Beanshell script which prevents it from successful execution. If your script relies on 3rd-party .jar libraries - make sure to include them in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

Going forward you can consider putting your Beanshell script in [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Script failure", ex);
}
```

This way you will get full information on the failure in [*jmeter.log*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) file

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), the reasons are in:

- Groovy is more Java-compliant
- Groovy has many [useful enhancements](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top of Java SDK
- [Groovy performs much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the required jar from following link https://jmeter-plugins.org/